# Visual Studio workspace not visible in VS2022

Tags: visual-studio, team-explorer

I have two versions of Visual Studio running side by side (2019 and 2022).
When I open VS 2019, I see that it is connected to TeamExplorer and has a workspace associated with the install.[image: 2019 Workspace]

When I open VS 2022, I don't see that workspace, although I am on the same computer.
[image: 2022 VS Workspace]

How can I work with the same projects that I have already downloade from Team Explorer in Vs 2022 and also check-in the code from VS 2022?

I can edit the code in VS 2022, but each time I have to check it in, I have to save the file, open VS 2019 and then check-in the project.

I want the option to check-in from either version of Visual Studio as the files are getting checked in the same repository.

Edit: Yes the VS 2022 is connected to the Visual Studio Online TFS.

[image: Vs 2022 Connected Image]

Comment: Did you connect Visual Studio 2022 to the Team project from the Team Explorer page?

Comment: @jessehouwing Yes. I edited the post to show that VS2022 is connected.

Comment: Tick the "Show remote workspaces" checkbox, visualstudio.com sounds pretty remote.

Comment: @HansPassant Nope, that doesn't work for some reason.